# Difference between mimetypes: audio/mpeg and audio/x-mpeg

Tags: audio

This is not a programming question. But I see many such questions here.. So i'm asking this question too.. I need to know the basic differences between mimetypes audio/mpeg and audio/x-mpeg.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
suffix   mimetype
mp2      audio/x-mpeg;
mp3      audio/x-mpeg;
mpga     audio/mpeg;
```

suffix name is different,that is different. Can help you.

Comment: suffix is not the correct difference. audio/mpeg is used for mp3 extensions too: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3003